# how to color rows in gsheets like in openpyxl?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, gspread, pygsheets

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
import pygsheets
import os

data = [
    [3, 'test', 1],
    [1, 'test', 2],
    [1, 'test', 3],
    [2, 'test', 4],
    [3, 'test', 5],
    [3, 'test', 6],
    [4, 'test', 7],
    [9, 'test', 8]]

write_path = "output2.xlsx"
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["value", "comment", "index"])

with pd.ExcelWriter(write_path) as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(write_path)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")   

# Create a color map
tohex = lambda r,g,b,a: '%02X%02X%02X%02X' % (a,r,g,b)
tab20c = cm.tab20c(np.linspace(0, 1, 20))
tab20c = np.array(tab20c * 255, dtype=int)
tab20c = iter([tohex(*tab20c[i,:]) for i in range(20)])

colours = {}
next_colour = 'FFFF0000' # start with red

for cells in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=1, max_col=1):
    cell = cells[0]

    try:
        colour = colours[cell.value]
    except KeyError:
        colours[cell.value] = next_colour
        colour = next_colour
        next_colour = next(tab20c)    # get the next colour in the colormap

    cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color=colour, end_color=colour, fill_type='solid')

wb.save(write_path) 


#authorization
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='C:/Users/Mikadincic/Google Drive/Python/Jazler Database Project/Jazler Database Project-0e56629e2784.json', no_cache=True)

#open the google spreadsheet (where 'PY to Gsheet Test' is the name of my sheet)
sh = gc.open('Jazler spotovi')

#select the first sheet 
wks = sh[0]

#update the first sheet with df, starting at cell B2. 
wks.set_dataframe(dataframe_spotovi,(1,1))
```

Is there a way I can do this in Google Sheets? It would be much better to have a live preview of changes in sheet, instead of having to reopen files like I need to when writing to xlsx.

I tried with Google scripting (automatically convert xlsx in drive to Sheets), but it doesnt work when you just overwrite xlsx file. Anyhow, it would be better to do this directly in gspread or pygsheets.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are doing in the code. But if you wanna color the cells , in pygsheets (you can't color cells in gspread) you can use the following to color a cell

```
c1 = wks.cell('A1')
c1.color = (1.0,1.0,0.5,1.0) # Red, Green, Blue, Alpha
```